# What is east of Rhûn?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings

If you look at the map of Middle Earth (ignoring the circles)

[image: map]

You see that the world suddenly ends when the map reaches the right margin. What is east of Rhûn?

Comment: End of middle earth, I suppose and start of Arda which is a part of Ea. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth#Geography

Comment: Nice image, I wonder where you got that!

Comment: @PriestVallon we may never know the truth.

Comment: I have this map hanging in my man cave

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [**Encyclopedia of Arda**](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/r/rhun.html):

> Even Gandalf had never explored there, and though Aragorn had travelled there, we have no report of his doings.
>
> Of its ancient geography we can glean a little from the [Silmarillion](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/s/silmarillion.html):
>
> - far beyond the [Sea of Rhûn](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/s/seaofrhun.html) was another inland sea, the [Sea of Helcar](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/h/helcar.html),
> - and beyond that a range of red mountains known as the [Orocarni](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/o/orocarni.html).
> - Somewhere in the lost east, too, lay [Cuiviénen](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/c/cuivienen.html) and [Hildórien](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/h/hildorien.html), where *Elves* and *Men* first awoke: all the [Children of Ilúvatar](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/c/childrenofiluvatar.html) could trace their ancestries back to the eastward regions of Middle-earth.

[**Sea of Helcar**](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/h/helcar.html):

> [image: Helcar]
>
> On its eastern shoreline lay the mountains of the *Orocarni*, and at their feet on a small bay was the land *Cuiviénen*, where the first Elves awoke in Middle-earth.
>
> It was there that [Oromë](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/o/orome.html) discovered them, and ultimately led many of them on a [Great Journey](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/g/greatjourney.html) around the northern end of the Sea of Helcar as they set out for [Valinor](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/v/valinor.html) in the distant west.

[**Orocarni**](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/o/orocarni.html):

> [image: Orocarni]
>
> A lost range of mountains in the far east of Middle-earth, near *Cuiviénen*, beneath which the first Elves awoke.
>
> Called the Mountains of the East, the name *Orocarni* literally translates as *'Red Mountains'*.
>
> We know little more about them, except that they were apparently the source of the many streams that ran down into *Cuiviénen*.

[**Blue Wizards**](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/b/bluewizards.html):

> After landing in Middle-earth, they travelled directly into the far east with *Curunír* (better known as [Saruman](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/s/saruman.html)).
>
> The mission of the Blue Wizards was to travel to eastern lands occupied by [Sauron](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/s/sauron.html), and help to foment unrest among his subject peoples.
>
> Whether they succeeded or not, even Tolkien was unsure, though he imagined that they had probably failed. It's also uncertain why they remained in the east while *Curunír* returned

Comment: It might be better to remove the images, given that they show conflicting information.

Comment: Those maps are based on ones found in _Volume 4_ of _[The History of Middle-earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_History_of_Middle-earth)_. I encourage people to click the links I provided if they want to know more. There is simply too much information to quote everything here, my answer would become _a wall of text_.

Answer (score 4):

There is not a great amount of detail about what is east of Rhun.

Taken from [The lord of the rings wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Rh%C3%BBn):

> Of its ancient geography we can glean a little from The Silmarillion; far beyond the Sea of Rhûn was another inland sea, the Sea of Helcar, and beyond that a range of red mountains known as the Orocarni (Red Mountains). Somewhere in the lost east, too, lay Cuiviénen and Hildórien, where Elves and Men first awoke: all the Children of Ilúvatar could trace their ancestries back to the eastward regions of Middle-earth.

Some other facts:

Dorwinion is situated in Rhun and this is where the easterlings reside.

Four of the seven clans of the dwarves also live there.

It is also home to lost Elves such as Avari and Úmanyar.

Answer (score 2):

There are no other countries or lands beyond Rhun. Like Russia it is all Rhun past the eastern borders of the map. To the southeast is another land called Khand.

Answer (score -1):

I used to own (for a decade) this huge wall-map of all points in Middle Earth beyond Rhun, beyond the Northern Wastesand the Icebay of Forochel, and beyond Far Harad. I got it as a fold-out from this magazine I'd bought about Middle Earth, and I've seen thumbnail images of it online.

Beyond the great desert Haradwaith, and its dozen or so oasis points, there were heavily forested shores with one particular (rain)forest about twice the size as Mirkwood. And south of this, heavily forested islands. It even showed Beleriand, as it was before it sank, with a great depiction of that big forest in Beleriand ("Taur-En-something") compared to Mirkwood's size.

Out east of Rhun and Khand,ran a mountain-range notably grander than the Misty and Blue mountains.